# Resuming a suspended state machine workflow instance in Windows Workflow Foundation 4

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, state-machine

I currently have a State Machine running as a Windows Workflow Foundation 4 Web Service. This solution is for long running workflows so it also utilizes the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore. The problem I have is that I can’t find a solution to Resuming a Suspended workflow instance. The examples I’ve seen online don’t seem to apply for a State Machine. The confusion seems to come from the fact that I don’t have an endpoint to reference which is needed to create the proper WorflowControlClient object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a web.config file in the same subdirectory of my service. Then for each Receive action I had to define an endpoint in the newly created web.config. I was then able to add an additional endpoint definition as a workflowControlEndpoint.

```
<endpoint address="wce" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="wceEndpoint" kind="workflowControlEndpoint"/>
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="WorkFlowCreated" contract="IWorkFlowCreated" />
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="WorkFlowUpdated" contract="IWorkFlowUpdated" />
```

Then it became possible to create the WorkflowControlClient

```
WorkflowControlClient controlClient = new WorkflowControlClient(
  new BasicHttpBinding(), 
  new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://sitepath/general/1.0.0/General.xamlx/wce")));
controlClient.Unsuspend(instanceId);</code>
```